# Does How to Train Your Dragon TV series follow on from the movie and build up to the new movie?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon, dreamworks-dragons

Having not watched all of the TV series on the cartoon network, does the TV series follow on from the events of the first *How to Train Your Dragon* movie, and build up towards the plot of the new *How to Train Your Dragon 2* movie?

Or is the TV series a completely separate collection of stories in the same universe?

I.e. Can someone who has not watched the entirety of the TV series watch the new movie without missing any information from the TV series?

Comment: There so different in the first movie hiccup is astrids girlfriend in the end but in the TV series they aren't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it bridges the gap between the first and second movies.**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riders_of_berk#Plot):

> Following directly after the events of How To Train Your Dragon but
>   before How to Train Your Dragon 2, Riders of Berk follows Hiccup as he
>   tries to keep balance within the new cohabitation of Dragons and
>   Vikings. Alongside keeping up with Berk's newest installment — A
>   Dragon Training Academy — Hiccup, Toothless, and the rest of the
>   Viking Teens are put to the test when they are faced with new worlds
>   harsher than Berk, new dragons that can't all be trained, and new
>   enemies who are looking for every reason to destroy the harmony
>   between Vikings and Dragons all together.

As for whether you can watch the movie without having seen the TV show or not, I'd wager to say you could. There may be some references you won't get, but I can't imagine the story writers for the second movie would make it completely impossible to enjoy without having watch 40 episodes of a tie-in TV show.